# how to play video from gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i write a code using asp.net C# to generate a thumbnail when a video file selected using fileupload control, and display it in gridview. so, what i wanna do is when image in gridview was clicked, it should play the video corresponding to the video where the particular thumbnail is created without involving database?

Comment: Help us to help you! In other words if you have any code please provide it to us, so we can help you!

Comment: @Haris well, my question here is is it possible to dynamically display image in gridview and play video that correspond to that image without involving database? Because all tutorials that i found in internet involving database. so, in other hand my question is still not reached the level of how to write the code. hope u understand what i'm saying here.

Answer (score 0):

There must be a Jquery plugin that solves the problem. I know there is many jQuery video plugins out there, just search for it. Why would you involve database? Can't you just include video files in your project and create a link from your images?
I dont know if this will solve your problem but worth checking out:

[Simple jQuery video plugin](http://smple.com/videoGallery/)

If you decide to use database I would suggest to keep it simple and use MySQL which is free and easy to setup.